# '\n' Prints extra space in ncurses C++

Tags: c++, newline, ncurses

I am trying to write a basic app in `C++` using `ncurses` library. All I wanted was to **print out characters that user presses** manually. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  initscr();            // Initialize the curses library
  timeout(0);           // Set getch() to be non-blocking
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE); // Enable special keys
  noecho();             // Disable automatic echoing of characters

  bool continue_ = true;
  
  while (continue_) {
    int c = getch();

    if (c != ERR) {
      switch (c) {
        case 27:
          continue_ = false;
          break;
        case KEY_ENTER:
        case '\r':
          std::cout << '\n'; // prints extra space
          break;
        default:
          std::cout << (char)c;
          break;
      } 
      std::cout.flush(); // without this, characters only appear after pressing enter
    }
  }
  
  endwin(); // End curses mode
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I press `enter key`, it prints the `newline character ('\n')`, but with **extra spaces**. Here's sample output:

```
Some text
         After Enter:
                     I am going forward
                                       why?
```

*Note*: I realized that extra space count is equal to keys I pressed (not including enter).

Comment: Try using `\r\n` instead?

Comment: Well, you are reading the carriage return and throwing it away. Then you are not seeing a carriage return on the terminal. What did you expect? ;-) If you redirect the output to a file I suppose you won't see spaces (0x20) characters at all in the file -- what you see is cursor positioning via (absence of) terminal control characters (here: CR), not ASCII output.

Comment: You are mixing **ncurses** screen input/output management, and `std::cout`.  That'll confuse ncurses, because it won't be updating its internal shadow copy of the screen state when `std::cout` sneak characters out behind ncurses's back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use printw instead:

```
    ...
    case '\r':
      printw("\n");
      break;
    default:
      printw("%c",c);
      break;
   ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).